# If first word is $var then print the whole line except first two words

Tags: bash, command-line

I have a log file like bellow.

```
130023432 195047 /media/ismail/SSDWorking/book-collection/_Books/book 1.epub
130023433 195047 /media/ismail/SSDWorking/book-collection/_Books/book 2.epub
130023431 195047 /media/ismail/SSDWorking/book-collection/_Books/book 3.epub
```

I have a variable, `var=130023432`

I want to say if first word equals to `$var`, then print all except the first two words.

So, in this case the output will be:

```
/media/ismail/SSDWorking/book-collection/_Books/book 2.epub
```

What I have tried so far is `grep -oP "(?<=$var \d+ ).*$'"` but it gives error `grep: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length`

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `grep -oP "$var \d+ \K.*"` works.

Comment: `awk -v var="$var" '$1 == var {print}' | cut -d" " -f3` also works.

Comment: If you change `{print}` to `{$1=$2=""; print $0}` then you will not need to pipe to `cut` and it will work with any type or amount of whitespace. Also, if you have an answer that works you can post it as an answer then accept it in a day or two. Makes the question/answer easier to search for.

Comment: @doneal24 I think there is a space behind `/media/....`. How can I remove that?

Comment: Is the space present in your input file? I did a cut&paste from your input and I don't see a trailing space. The two leading spaces are annoying and unwanted.

Comment: @doneal24 no there is no space in the input file, but i think the space after `195047` is there.

Comment: @AhmadIsmail: look my answer, space issue solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this short `awk` (`sub` is `sed` like, to substitute a pattern or a regex):

```
var=130023432 awk -v var="$var" '$1==var{sub($1" "$2" ", ""); print}' file
```

or simply:

```
awk -v var="130023432" '$1==var{sub($1" "$2" ", ""); print}' file
```

```
/media/ismail/SSDWorking/book-collection/_Books/book 1.epub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` for this.

```
var="$var" awk '$1 == ENVIRON["var"] { $1 = $2 = ""; print substr($0, 3) }' logfile
```

Output using your example

```
/media/ismail/SSDWorking/book-collection/_Books/book 1.epub
```

I've avoided the `awk -v var="$var" '...'}` construct because `-v` processes its values for backslashes, etc. whereas an environment variable is left untouched. If you really want to go this route then try this (not POSIX):

```
awk -v var="${var//\\/\\\\}" '$1 == var { $1 = $2 = ""; print substr($0, 3) }' logfile
```

Comment: Note that you have 2 leading spaces in the output that OP don't want IMHO

Comment: @GillesQuénot thanks fixed, although I was sure awk was supposed to recalculate $0 after assignment to a field $1

Comment: No, it's a pitfall. You confuse with `$1=$1` to normalize spaces

Answer (score 0):

`sed`

```
$ sed -En "s~$var[^/]*(.*)~\1~p" input_file
```

`pcregrep`

```
$ pcregrep -o1 "$var[^/]*(.*)" input_file
```

`grep`

```
$ grep -oP "$var[^/]*\K.*" input_file
```

`awk`

```
$ awk -v var="$var" '$1==var {print $(NF-1),$NF}' input_file
```

**Output**

```
/media/ismail/SSDWorking/book-collection/_Books/book 1.epub
```

Comment: no command works. error `bad math expression: operand expected at `^/'``. The awk command output `Duffy) (Z-Library).epub`